# Form in Footer and multi form in Django

Tags: django, forms

Hello Is there any way to accept a input from footer? I have a footer which is for Newsletter signup. Users insert their mail there. How could I accept that data? Do I need to send form via views every time. or there is a way to accept form from that included template code?

Well I also have a feedback form in the footer which in included in all the pages I want the feedback to be stored in my DB. I cannot figure out how I can accept the form data from all pages. (Sending forms in all page through views is possible But I think there is A easy (good Looking) idea) and also There are more them one Post method. I really don't know how to Explain. But I expect you  can understand me.

Answer (score 0):

I breakdown the your multiform/newsletter signup in steps as below:

1. Define view the post view
2. Add route to the url.py
3. In your html template add action in form tag example for
4. Validate input in your defined view
5. Save it.

That's it.